# Open terminator settings after activating paste on right click

Tags: gnome, 18.10, terminator, context-menu

I installed terminator in Ubuntu 18.10 and want to have putty style pasting (right click = paste). This works, but unfortunately I'm unable to open the settings now. The settings were displayed in a context menu that shows after right clicking in the terminal.

How can I access the settings? I tried different things like `ctrl` + right click or `shift` + right click, which doesn't work.

### I'm not searching for a workaround!

I'm aware that terminators settings were stored in `~/.config/terminator/config`. So it's simply to set `putty_paste_style` to `False` to access the settings again. But I want to keep the putty-like copy style permanent and want to access the settings without resetting `putty_paste_style`, changing settings and having to change the config again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option 1.. on the Keyboard Press <kbd>menu</kbd> key (Adjacent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in this pic)   [image]

Option 2.. press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Please note that Option 2 is printing `;2~` along with right click options..

below shows when I pressed above two options..

[image]

Comment: Both works, `menu` key is on `fn + F2` using my logitech keyboard. Thanks for your usefull answear! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Keybindings" to set a key shortcut for open preferences ( Let's say "Ctrl -P" to open preferences ), Use this shortcut to open preferences directly even after you set putty_paste_style in Terminator ( Take a new session to get it reflected with the changes )